# Protractor: Failed: Element not found. Wait timed out after 7030ms

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

Currently I am having an issue on this e2e Automation tool (protractor) and I am struggling with fixing time out issue in protractor with below code.

**Utill.ts**

````
    public async addSection(section: ISection) {
        const rightPanel = element(by.css('.right-panel'));
        await waitUntilPresenceOf(rightPanel);
        const sectionObj = new IdToClassMap[FORM_FIELD_IDS.SECTION](section.name);
        const newSectionElement = sectionObj.getFieldElementFromMenu()

        await Promise.all([
            waitUntilPresenceOf(newSectionElement),
            waitUntilPresenceOf(rightPanel)
        ]);
        await browser.driver.executeScript(dragAndDrop, await newSectionElement.getWebElement(), await rightPanel.getWebElement());
        await sectionObj.fillDetails(section);
        await save();

        this.form.sections.push(section);
        await browser.sleep(2000);
    }
export const waitUntilPresenceOf = async (
  finder: ElementFinder,
  errMessage: string = 'Element not found.',
  time: number = 7000
): Promise<boolean> => {
  return await browser.wait(
    protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(finder),
    time,
    errMessage
  );
};```

Gone through many sites and also added the `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` to config.ts but nothing worked for me.
And also I Set timeout properties for  allScriptsTimeout:110000 & getPageTimeout:110000 in config file but same issue persist.

I already tried many changes but the error is present anyway.

I set 110000 in; allScriptsTimeout, getPageTimeout and defaultTimeoutInterval in conf.js (And basically in every timeout flag I set an high number.
How can I solve the below error , Can any one assist me
 Message:
    Failed: Element not found.
    Wait timed out after 7030ms
````

Comment: that means your element still is not present

Comment: Is there anything to change in my code

Comment: first you need to find out why it's not present - bad locator, or the function doesn't wait long enough

Comment: I am new to protractor what exact change I have to do can you assist me

Comment: open the page in the browser where it fails. Copy your locator of element that says not found (css or xpath), paste it in elements tab of chrome's console. see if the locator is correct, if not correct it, otherwise let me know